# Creating 3 different lists with the use of text file & relations

Tags: java, arrays, file, object

I am writing a program where I have 3 different files: paitients, doctors & visits. I have imported them in & they are loading. I have created 3 clases:
Visits relation to Paitient paitient; Doctor doctor and Date of the visit;
Doctor where it has relation `List<Visits> listOfDoctorVisits;`
Paitient where it has relation `List<Visits> listOfPaitientVisits;`

I need to write code where when I read a file of Visits a new object is made & added to the list. But then a doctor has to has his visits in the `List<Visits> listOfDoctorVisits` & paitient in `listOfPaitientVisits.`

Could you advise on how to edit the code so it would check the visits file and create a vist list for the doctor & the paitient?

```
 List<Wizyty> wizytyList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        File fileWizyty = new File("src/com/company/pliki/wizyty.txt");
        Scanner readerWizyty = new Scanner(fileWizyty);
        readerWizyty.nextLine();
        while (readerWizyty.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] data = readerWizyty.nextLine().trim().split("\t");

            Lekarze lekarze1 = lekarze.stream()
                    .filter(m -> m.getIdLekarza() == Integer.parseInt(data[0]))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(null);

            Pacjenci pacjenci1 = pacjent.stream()
                    .filter(m -> m.getIdPacjenta() == Integer.parseInt(data[1]))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(null);

            Wizyty wizyta = new Wizyty(lekarze1, pacjenci1, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(data[2]));

            wizytyList.add(wizyta);
        }
        readerWizyty.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error File Wizyty");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Sample Doctor text file:
(ID, Surname, Name, Speciality, DOB, NIP number, Pesel number)

```
Id_lekarza  Nazwisko    Imie    Specjalnosc Data_urodzenia  NIP PESEL
       23   Kadaj       Monika  laryngolog  1965-03-16  879-122-69-94   65031687654
```

Sample Paitient text file:
(ID, Surname, Name, Pesel number, DOB)

```
Id_pacjenta Nazwisko    Imie    PESEL   Data_urodzenia
     100    Kowal   Waldemar    01211309876 2001-1-13
```

Sample Visits text file:
(Doctor ID, Paitient ID, Date of visit)

```
Id_lekarza  Id_pacjenta Data_wizyty
  23             124    2006-12-13
```

Comment: The relationships and your requirements are not yet clear, at least not to me. What is your goal? Why do you need three lists? Wouldn't you rather have two maps that show the relations  between `Doctor -> List<Visit>` and `Patient -> List<Visit>` ? Do you have sample inputs and can you share the expected result?

Comment: So I would need:

Doctor to have his visits
Paitient to have his visits
Later on I have methods to create such as: which doctors has most visits, which paitient has most visits, top 5 oldest doctors etc.

So I guess 2 lists will work just fine, or do you thing 3 would be needed?

Comment: Can you share sample data? I mean the content of your files. Just for example, with fake names and ids.

Comment: Sure @Eritrean I've added it to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have getters in your `Lekarze` and `Pacjenci` classes, you could just add the `Wizyty` object to `listOfDoctorVisits` and `listOfPaitientVisits` of the current found doctor and patient :

```
 while (readerWizyty.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] data = readerWizyty.nextLine().trim().split("\t");

        Lekarze lekarze1 = lekarze.stream()
                .filter(m -> m.getIdLekarza() == Integer.parseInt(data[0]))
                .findAny()
                .orElse(null);

        Pacjenci pacjenci1 = pacjent.stream()
                .filter(m -> m.getIdPacjenta() == Integer.parseInt(data[1]))
                .findAny()
                .orElse(null);

        Wizyty wizyta = new Wizyty(lekarze1, pacjenci1, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(data[2]));

        wizytyList.add(wizyta);
        if(lekarze1 != null) {
           lekarze1.getListOfDoctorVisits().add(wizyta);
        }
        if(pacjenci1 != null) {
           pacjenci1.getListOfPaitientVisits().add(wizyta);
        }
    }
```

But be aware, currently you are iterating over and over the doctors list and patients list for each and every line in the visits file. I would recomend to read the visits file first and create two maps: 1) doctorId to visits and 2) patientId to visits and use those maps to populate the doctors list and patients list. See below example which dose this (for simplicity, I am using lombok and included the three classes as nested inner classes, but you can create your own `getter` and `toString`, and move the inner classes to own file)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

public class Example {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DTF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    private static final Pattern DELIMITER = Pattern.compile("\t");

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final var fileWizyty   = "src/com/company/pliki/wizyty.txt";
        final var fileLekarze  = "src/com/company/pliki/lekarze.txt";
        final var filePacjenci = "src/com/company/pliki/pacjenci.txt";

        final List<Wizyty> wizytyList = readWizyty(fileWizyty);

        final Map<Integer,List<Wizyty>> lekarzaMapieWizyty = wizytyList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Wizyty::getIdLekarza));

        final Map<Integer,List<Wizyty>> pacjentaMapieWizyty = wizytyList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Wizyty::getIdPacjenta));

        final List<Lekarze>  lekarzeList   = readLekarze(fileLekarze, lekarzaMapieWizyty);
        final List<Pacjenci> pacjenciList = readPacjenci(filePacjenci, pacjentaMapieWizyty);
    }

    private static List<Wizyty> readWizyty(final String pathToFile) throws IOException {
        try (final Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get(pathToFile))) {
            return input.skip(1)
                .map(Wizyty::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

    private static List<Lekarze> readLekarze(final String pathToFile,
            final Map<Integer, List<Wizyty>> map) throws IOException {

        try (final Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get(pathToFile))) {
            return input.skip(1)
                    .map(line  -> new Lekarze(line, map.get(Integer.parseInt(DELIMITER.split(line)[0]))))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

    private static List<Pacjenci> readPacjenci(final String pathToFile,
            final Map<Integer, List<Wizyty>> map) throws IOException {

        try (final Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get(pathToFile))) {
            return input.skip(1)
                .map(line  -> new Pacjenci(line, map.get(Integer.parseInt(DELIMITER.split(line)[0]))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

    @Getter
    @ToString
    static class Lekarze {
        int idLekarza;
        String nazwisko;
        String imie;
        String specjalnosc;
        LocalDate dataUrodzenia;
        String nip;
        String pesel;
        List<Wizyty> wizytyList;

        Lekarze (final String line, final List<Wizyty> wizytyList){
            final String[] data = DELIMITER.split(line);
            idLekarza = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            nazwisko = data[1];
            imie = data[2];
            specjalnosc = data[3];
            dataUrodzenia = LocalDate.parse(data[4], DTF);
            nip = data[5];
            pesel = data[6];
            this.wizytyList = new ArrayList<>(wizytyList);
        }
    }

    @Getter
    @ToString
    static class Pacjenci {
        int idPacjenta;
        String nazwisko;
        String imie;
        String pesel;
        LocalDate dataUrodzenia;
        List<Wizyty> wizytyList;

        Pacjenci (final String line, final List<Wizyty> wizytyList){
            final String[] data = DELIMITER.split(line);
            idPacjenta = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            nazwisko = data[1];
            imie = data[2];
            pesel = data[3];
            dataUrodzenia = LocalDate.parse(data[4], DTF);
            this.wizytyList = new ArrayList<>(wizytyList);
        }
    }

    @Getter
    @ToString
    static class Wizyty {
        int idLekarza;
        int idPacjenta;
        LocalDate dataWizyty;

        Wizyty (final String line){
            final String[] data = DELIMITER.split(line);
            idLekarza = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            idPacjenta = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
            dataWizyty = LocalDate.parse(data[2],DTF);
        }
    }
}
```